# Linked list printing the same element over and over

Tags: c, linked-list, dynamic-memory-allocation, singly-linked-list, function-definition

I have a linked list which is formed by each element taken by the user input.
Dynamic:
User inputs how many disciplines/classes names they want, each individual input differs.

At the moment my code is printing the last element added by the user as many times as the user has input the classes (repeated, e.g: last class added is programming, it prints 3x `programming`) rather than printing each individual class ( e.g. programming, maths, physics etc).

Here is my code:

```
typedef struct SList {
    char *number;
    char *class;
    struct SList *next;
} List;

List *Add(List *list, char *ucNumNew, char *uc) {
    List *element = (List *)malloc(sizeof(List));
    if (element != NULL) {
        element->number = ucNumNew;
        element->class = uc;
        element->next = list;
    }
    return element;
}

void PrintListInts(List *list) {
    while (list != NULL) {
        printf("%s", list->number);
        printf("%s", list->class);
        list = list->next;
    }
}

void InserirDados() {
    int totalActividades = 0, countActividades = 0, countRealizado = 0, realizadoNum, totalSessoes, countSessoes = 0;
    int ucsCount, wordCount = 0, count = 0, stringLength, totalCaracteresUcs, i = 0;
    const size_t bufsize = 100;
    char palavra[bufsize];
    char *ucNum, *uc;
    char ucNumNew[bufsize];
    char actividade[bufsize];
    List *list = NULL;

    while (fgets(palavra, bufsize, stdin) != NULL) {
        if (palavra[0] == '\n')
            break;
        ucNum = strtok(palavra, "-");
        uc = strtok(NULL, "-");
        if (uc != NULL) {
            removerEspacosExtra(uc);
            stringLength = strlen(uc);
            wordCount += stringLength;
        }
        if (ucNum != NULL) {
            removerEspacosExtra(ucNum);
            strcpy(ucNumNew, ucNum);
        }
        list = Add(list, ucNumNew, uc);
        count++;
        i++;
    }
    PrintListInts(list);
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please provide code that is at least compiled.

Comment: You never allocate new memory for your strings. You are just assigning a pointer to `char ucNumNew[bufsize];` and `uc` which points inside `char palavra[bufsize];` for each element. That means all nodes point to same memory and whatever was stored there last, will be visible for all nodes. This also means that all the memory would become invalid after leaving `InserirDados` as these are local arrays.

Comment: thanks @Gerhardh so do you mean this bit here, where I am allocating memory: `List *element = (List *) malloc(sizeof(List));` I would need to have allocated a new memory place for each time the user adds the new input?

Comment: Replace `element->number = ucNumNew; element->class = uc;` with `element->number = strdup(ucNumNew); element->class = strdup(uc);` Don't forget to free the `strdup` memory when the node is to be deleted.

Comment: That `malloc` only reserves memory for the struct but no memory where you pointers can point to.

Comment: thanks @kaylum that seems to sort it, I now understand why Gerhardh. Yeah that isn't right, I have just translated the names to english for you to understand better but in my code its all in another language. I have edited now. thanks both

Answer (score 0):

For starters in the structure definition there is no data member with the name `seg` used in this statement'

```
element->seg = list;
```

There is a data member with the name `next`.

As for the problem then in this call of the function Add

```
list = Add(list,ucNumNew,uc);
```

there are passed the same local array `ucNumNew` and the same pointer `uc`.

```
char ucNumNew[bufsize];
```

So all nodes in the list at least store pointers to the first character of the same local array.

```
element->number = ucNumNew;
element->class = uc;
```

As a result the program outputs the last content of the same local array for each node of the list.

You need to allocate memory dynamically for data members of nodes and copy there the passed data.